# AngularJS communication between controller and directive

Tags: javascript, web, angularjs

How to get some data from controller and use it inside directive thats not a problem. 
But I stack with such situation when I need get data from directive and use it in my controller.

For exmpl:

My controller:

```
function MyController($scope, $location, myDirective) {
    "use strict";

    // here i need use scope.importantValue and create() method from directive

}
```

My directive:

```
        .directive("myDirective", function() {
"use strict";
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        data: '=',
    },
    link: function(scope, elm) {
        scope.importantValue = "value";

        function create() {
            console.log("Directive works...");
        }

};
})
```

How I can use variables or/and methods from directive inside my controller?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: you are not suppose to do it

Comment: We moved to directive some part of code that similar for few views and this directive contains some variables that can be used in other parts of project. I wanna know is it posible to use this variables in a controller or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to make both your controller and directive get `importantValue` and `create()` from a service.

```
angular.module(/* Your module */).service('sharedData', function () {
    return {
        importantValue: "value",
        create: function () {
            console.log("Directive works...");
        }
    };
});
```

Now you can inject `sharedData` into your directive and controller and access `importantValue` and `create()` from either place.

Comment: Good! That what I really need!+